# Centering chapter titles with ConteXt

Tags: context

How to center chapter titles to have `chapter I: First chapter` and not

`Chapter I:
First chapter`

```
 \mainlanguage[fr]

  \setuphead[chapter]
      [commandbefore={:\,},
       header=empty,
       alternative=middle]

  \setuphead[subsection][style=bold]

  \setuphead[section]
      [distance=\zeropoint,
       style=bold,
       commandbefore={\space\endash\space}]

  \setuphead[title][commandbefore={},alternative=middle,header=empty]

  \setuplayout
     [height=middle,
     width=middle,
     backspace=2cm,
     topspace=10mm,       
     bottomspace=10mm,
     header=10mm,
     footer=10mm,
     footerdistance=10mm,
     headerdistance=10mm]

   \definelayout
     [firstpage]
     [header=empty]


  \setupheader[text][after=\hrule]

   \setupheadertexts[{\getmarking[section]}]
             [pagenumber]
             [{\getmarking[chapter]}]
             [pagenumber]


   \setuppagenumbering[alternative=,location=]


  \setuplabeltext[fr][chapter=Chapitre ]

  \definestructureconversionset
     [structure]
     [n, R, n, n, n]

  \definestructureconversionset
     [digits]
     [n, n, n, n, n]

  \setupheads[sectionconversionset=structure]

  \setuplist[chapter][style=bold,width=5mm]

  \starttext

  \starttitle[title={\bf Sommaire}] 
  \placelist
    [chapter,section,subsection]
    [criterium=all,
     alternative=c]

  \stoptitle

 \startchapter[title=First chapter]
 \dorecurse{10}{\input ward}
 \startsection[title=Fist section]
 \dorecurse{10}{\input ward} 
 \startsubsection[title=First subsection]
 \dorecurse{10}{\input ward}
 \stopsubsection
 \stopsection
 \stopchapter
 \startchapter[title=Second chapter]
 \dorecurse{10}{\input ward}
 \startsection[title=Second section]
 \dorecurse{10}{\input ward}
 \startsubsection[title=Second subsection]
 \dorecurse{10}{\input ward}
 \stopsubsection
 \stopsection
 \stopchapter
 \stoptext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your own alternative for that but that's fairly straightforward.  Go to [`strc-ren.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/deab0bfe7f4be57121779e93bf291e518fda7cf3/tex/context/base/mkiv/strc-ren.mkiv#L731-L753) and look for `\??headrenderings:\v!middle`.  Copy the definition to your file and make the necessary adjustments.

```
\mainlanguage[fr]

\defineheadalternative
  [centered]
  [alternative=vertical,
   renderingsetup=headrenderings:centered]

\startsetups[headrenderings:centered]
    \vbox {
        \headsetupspacing
        \veryraggedcenter
        \let\\\endgraf
        \let\crlf\endgraf
        \ifconditional\headshownumber
            \strut
            \headnumbercontent
            %\par % <-- commented out
        \else
            \fakeheadnumbercontent
        \fi
        \begstrut
        \headtextcontent
        \endstrut
    }
\stopsetups

\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [commandbefore={:\,},
   header=empty,
   alternative=centered]

\setuplabeltext[fr][chapter=Chapitre ]

\starttext

\startchapter[title=First chapter]
  \input ward
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This has nothing to do with the subject but as you are a specialist of ConteXt, is the code clean ? Can we optimize it ?

Comment: @Fabrice It looks pretty clean already.  I'd harmonize the indentation and remove the unused structure conversion sets.  I have come to adapt Hans' indentation scheme, as demonstrated in, e.g. the [LuaTeX manual](https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/master/manual/luatex-style.tex).  Also I'm not really a specialist of ConTeXt.

Comment: `I have come to adapt Hans indentation scheme` That is to say ?

Comment: @Fabrice Oh, that's hard to explain :) Just take a look at the file I linked above.

Comment: I wanted to test by compiling the file luatex.tex using the simple command `context luatex.tex` but it does not work because I do not understand why `\ startdocument ... \ endocument `while we use ConteXt.

Comment: @Fabrice [`\start...\stopdocument`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/deab0bfe7f4be57121779e93bf291e518fda7cf3/tex/context/base/mkiv/file-job.mkvi#L298-L332) is only a thin wrapper around `\start...\stoptext` which sets some additional variables.  For me the LuaTeX manual typesets fine (with some missing fonts which I don't have).

Answer (score 1):

Much easier: to get what you want, you need `align=center`.

### Thus:

```
\setuppapersize[A5]
\setuplabeltext[chapter=CHAPTER~]

\setuphead[chapter][
    header=empty,
    align=center,
    style=bold,
  numbercommand=\groupedcommand{}{:},
   %commandbefore={:\,},
   %distance=0em,
    after={\blank[3cm]},
    ]

\starttext

\chapter{Title of chapter}

The first paragraph begins 3 cm below the title. In this chapter, we will discuss...

\stoptext
```

#### Adapted from the [wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuphead#First_example):

```
\setuppapersize[A5]
\setuplabeltext[chapter=CHAPTER~]

\setuphead[chapter][
    header=empty,
    alternative=middle,
    style=bold,
    numbercommand=\groupedcommand{}{\blank[2cm]},
    after={\blank[3cm]},
    ]

\starttext

\chapter{Title of chapter}

The first paragraph begins 3 cm below the title. In this chapter, we will discuss...

\stoptext
```