# ConTeXt: is it possible not to apply setuplayout to part and chapter headers?

Tags: context, layout

I need to have space for margin notes on my document, which I have done with the following `\setuplayout` ([from this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542444/213111)):

```
\setuplayout[topspace=10mm,
             width=middle,
             height=270mm,
             header=10mm,
             headerdistance=0pt,
             footerdistance=0pt,
             footer=0pt,
             bottom=10mm,
             bottomdistance=0pt,
             cutspace=60mm,
             rightmargin=50mm,
             rightmargindistance=5mm]
```

However, this layout obviously affect `part` and `chapter` head placements.
[image]

So, is it possible not to apply `\setuplayout` to `part` and `chapter` headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, is it possible not to apply `\setuplayout` to `part` and `chapter` headers?

**No**, this is not possible.  The settings in `\setuplayout` determine the dimensions of the paper that the content will be printed on and since parts and chapters are going to be printed on the same paper as the rest of the document, it is illogical to have `\setuplayout` somehow “ignore” them.

What you want to do is still possible<sup>*</sup> by setting the `width` key in `\setuphead` for the specified entries.

## Using the default head alternative

The default headrendering will then adjust the size of the textblock to the specified width only for the heading.

<sup>* This is usually a sign that you were asking the wrong question.</sup>

```
\showgrid
\showframe

\setuplayout[topspace=10mm,
             width=middle,
             height=270mm,
             header=10mm,
             headerdistance=0pt,
             footerdistance=0pt,
             footer=0pt,
             bottom=10mm,
             bottomdistance=0pt,
             cutspace=60mm,
             rightmargin=50mm,
             rightmargindistance=5mm]

\setuphead
    [chapter]
    [width=\dimexpr\makeupwidth+\rightmargindistance+\rightmarginwidth\relax]

\starttext

\startchapter[title={A very long chapter name just for the example}]

\samplefile{knuth}

\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

[image]

## Using a custom head alternative

If you are using a different `alternative` than the default `normal`, then you will have to make it aware of the adapted width manually.  In the comments you mentioned that you are using a custom `alternative` based on [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442774/10995).  This is simple to adapt to the new requirements by setting `\hsize` to `\headwidth` inside the `\vbox` that contains the heading.  The dimension `\headwidth` is set to the `width` parameter that you supplied to `\setuphead` within the headrendering code.

```
\showgrid
\showframe

\setuplayout[topspace=10mm,
             width=middle,
             height=270mm,
             header=10mm,
             headerdistance=0pt,
             footerdistance=0pt,
             footer=0pt,
             bottom=10mm,
             bottomdistance=0pt,
             cutspace=60mm,
             rightmargin=50mm,
             rightmargindistance=5mm]

\defineheadalternative
  [centered]
  [alternative=vertical,
   renderingsetup=headrenderings:centered]

\startsetups[headrenderings:centered]
    \vbox {
        \ifzeropt\headwidth\else
            \hsize\headwidth
        \fi 
        \headsetupspacing
        \veryraggedcenter
        \let\\\endgraf
        \let\crlf\endgraf
        \ifconditional\headshownumber
            \strut
            \headnumbercontent
            %\par % <-- commented out
        \else
            \fakeheadnumbercontent
        \fi
        \begstrut
        \headtextcontent
        \endstrut
    }
\stopsetups

\setuplabeltext[en][chapter=Chapter ]

\setuphead
    [chapter]
    [width=\dimexpr\makeupwidth+\rightmargindistance+\rightmarginwidth\relax,
     commandbefore={:\,},
     alternative=centered]

\starttext

\startchapter[title={A very long chapter name just for the example}]

\samplefile{knuth}

\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I know I have to study english and particularly how to ask questions that correctly fit my thoughts... Well, however, your answer is great as always but it does not seems to work with `alternative`s, any idea?

Comment: @dpi I presume that `alternative` will select a different headrendering, I'll have a look.  Which `alternative` are you using?

Comment: Just a simple alternative based on this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442774/213111. I have take a look at https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkiv/strc-ren.mkiv#L598-L640 for the `normal` alternative but I do not really understand what is going on.

Comment: @dpi See the second part of the updated answer.